# Error in Internet Explorer 11 for website automation using vb6

Tags: vb6, windows-10, internet-explorer-11

I am automating the website ("http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/UserLogin/LoginHome.html") filling using vb6.
The code which works in IE10 & below,

```
Dim WithEvents Web  As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer     
Private Sub Form_Load()     
    Set Web = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer  
    Web.Visible = True  
    Web.Navigate "http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/UserLogin/LoginHome.html"    
End Sub     
Private Sub Web_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)     
On Error GoTo aaa       
    msgbox "   URL: " & URL 
    if url = "http://incometaxindiaefiling.gov.in/e-Filing/UserLogin/LoginHome.html" then   
    Web.Document.getElementById("Login_userName").Value = "abcde1111h"  
    Web.Document.getElementById("Login_userName").onchange  
    Web.Document.getElementById("Login_password").Value = "123456789"   
    Web.Document.getElementById("dateField").Value = "15/09/1954"   
    end if      
Exit Sub        
aaa:        
MsgBox Err.Description & "   URL: " & URL       
End Sub 
Private Sub Web_OnQuit()        
    MsgBox "OnQuit fired"   
End Sub
```

In IE11 (Windows 10) I am facing the following problem with my code,

when navigated to above URL using SHDocVw.InternetExplorer control

First DocumentComplete event will be fired with URL being empty.
Then OnQuit event is fired. Then again DocumentComplete event is fired with  URL  'about:blank'

When I run the exe with ‘Run as admin’ option then it works in IE11 without any errors.

Please help.